# Two rules in antlr4 conflicts

Tags: antlr4

Here is a fragment of the g4 file.

```
expression:
    | K_CASE (K_WHEN expression K_THEN expression)+ K_ELSE expression K_END # caseexpr
    | ID LPAREN (expression (COMMA expression)*)? RPAREN                    # callexpr
```

lexer.g4

```
// case-when
CASE: 'case' | 'Case' | 'CASE';
WHEN: 'when' | 'When' | 'WHEN';
THEN: 'then' | 'Then' | 'THEN';
ELSE: 'else' | 'Else' | 'ELSE';
END: 'end' | 'End' | 'END';

ID: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*;
```

The `CASE WHEN ($name == "test") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` to be parsed as `caseexpr`，but the word `CASE` was treated as `ID`，and the error message is as below:

```
panic: syntax error: line 1:5, extraneous input 'WHEN' expecting '(' [recovered]
```

By the way, there is warning message when generating using antlr4

```
warning(125): XExprParser.g4:26:3: implicit definition of token CASE in parser
warning(125): XExprParser.g4:26:9: implicit definition of token WHEN in parser
warning(125): XExprParser.g4:26:25: implicit definition of token THEN in parser
warning(125): XExprParser.g4:26:43: implicit definition of token ELSE in parser
warning(125): XExprParser.g4:26:59: implicit definition of token END in parser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the second rule (starting with `K_CASE`) above the `ID PAREN ...`. But also ensure that the `K_CASE` token/keyword definition comes before the `ID` token definition in the lexer.

Moreover, if `ID` is a fragment, you should not refer to that from parser rules since it's not a tangible token, just a token-like definition to be used by other lexer rules.

Comment: Still not working, I just add some more output message. Thanks very much by the way.

Comment: I found there is a line `CODE_ID: ID -> type(ID);` in my lexer file. After removing that line, the issue is fixed.